# How to toggle class of a single element in a .map() function?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to toggle a class for a specific element inside a loop.

```
const ItemList: React.FC<ListItemUserProps> = (props) => {

  const { items } = props;

  const [showUserOpt, setShowUserOpt] = useState<boolean>(false);

  function toggleUserOpt() {
    setShowUserOpt(!showUserOpt);
  }

  const userOptVisible = showUserOpt ? 'show' : 'hide';

  return (
    <>
      {items.map((t) => (
        <React.Fragment key={t.userId}>
          <div
            className={`item ${userOptVisible}`}
            role="button"
            tabIndex={0}
            onClick={() => toggleUserOpt()}
            onKeyDown={() => toggleUserOpt()}
          >
            {t.userNav.firstName}
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};

export default ItemList;
```

When I click on an element, the class toggles for every single one.

Answer (score 2):

You can create another component that can have it's own state that can be toggled without effecting other sibling components' state:

Child:

```
const ItemListItem: React.FC<SomeInterface> = ({ item }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const userOptVisible = show ? "show" : "hide";

  const toggleUserOpt = (e) => {
    setShow((prevState) => !prevState);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`item ${userOptVisible}`}
      role="button"
      tabIndex={0}
      onClick={toggleUserOpt}
      onKeyDown={toggleUserOpt}
    >
      {item.userNav.firstName}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Parent:

```
const ItemList: React.FC<ListItemUserProps> = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {items.map((t) => (
        <ItemListItem key={t.userId} item={t} />
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply adding classes to the element, I would keep it simple and use a handler to toggle the class using pure JS.

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
   // example of simply toggling a class
   e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('selected');
};
```

Demo:

```js
const {
  useState,
} = React;

// dummy data
const data = Array(20).fill(null).map((i, index) => `item ${(index + 1).toString()}`);

function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState(data);
  
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('selected');
  };

  return ( 
    <div> 
      {items.map((item) => (
        <button key={item} onClick={handleClick}>{item}</button>
      ))} 
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```css
.selected {
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>



<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it'd be best if you kept track of the index so that you could target a single item in your list. As it stands the `boolean` is going to change the styling for all as you haven't specified which one should get the `className`.

Add a `useState` hook to keep track of it like:

```
const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);
```

Then create a new function:

```
function handleIndexOnClick(index) {
    setActive(index);
  }
```

Then in your `map()` function add `index`. You'll then need to pass `index` in to you className attribute and the `onClick` function. The end result for that bit should look like:

```
{items.map((t, index) => (
        <React.Fragment key={t.userId}>
          <div
            className={`item ${activeIndex && items[activeIndex] ? 'show' : 'hide }`}
            role="button"
            tabIndex={0}
            onClick={() => handleIndexOnClick(index)}
            onKeyDown={() => toggleUserOpt()}
          >
            {t.userNav.firstName}
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
```

Comment: this works for the initial click but if I select it again, it won't remove the class hence a toggle effect is not possible.